# How to convert locale formatted number to BigInteger in Java?

Tags: java, formatting, numbers, locale, biginteger

I searched a lot but nothing helped me :( Suppose I need convert 12.090.129.019.201.920.192.091.029.102.901.920.192.019.201.920 (in Portuguese group separator: .) to BigInteger value. How to do that conversion? I tried use NumberFormat, DecimalFormat and nothing works or I didn't on right way :(

Comment: How did you pass it in?  Was it literally that, or was it a String?

Comment: When I pass new BigInteger("12090129019201920192091029102901920192019201920") works well, but new BigInteger("12.090.129.019.201.920.192.091.029.102.901.920.192.019.201.920") generates an exception (as expected). I pass a string because I'm implementing a string converter to convert inputs from users forms. Is need provide an Locale instance to format I think... but I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get a [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) instance for a Portuguese [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), and then `parse` the number with it. This will also handle locale-specific decimal separators.

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("pt", "PT"));
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
BigDecimal decimal = (BigDecimal)df.parse("12.090.129.019.201.920.192.091.029.102.901.920.192.019.201.920");
BigInteger big = decimal.toBigInteger();
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/gN65j)**.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be more straightforward to remove the separators instead?  Java doesn't pay attention to those internally.

```
String num = "2.090.129.019.201.920.192.091.029.102.901.920.192.019.201.920";
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(num.replaceAll("\\.", ""));
```

If you need it back, then you can use NumberFormat.format() to get the value back.

Comment: This will break as soon as the locale is switched (say from Portugal to US). Joao's locale NumberFormat is much better.