# How can I shorten a BigInteger value?

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm trying to format BigInteger numbers to a more humanly readable form

Examples:

> 1000 -> 1.000K
>
> 5821 -> 5.821K
>
> 10500 -> 10.500K
>
> 101800 -> 101.800K
>
> 2000000 -> 2.000M
>
> 7800000 -> 7.800M
>
> 92150000 -> 92.150M
>
> 123200000 -> 123.200M
>
> 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 -> 1.000E
>
> 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 -> 1.000Z
>
> 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 -> 1.000Y
>
> 611 781 555 431 000 000 000 000 000 -> 611.781Y

I saw a method using long values, but for my purpose long cannot store big enough values so I have to use `BigInteger`s. How can I format it in such a way using BigInteger?

In my case, the max amount it is supposed to handle is:

> 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 and is formatted to 1.000B

<sub>**EDIT**

No, this is not a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753251/how-to-go-about-formatting-1200-to-1-2k-in-java). I have to use BigInteger for this to work and it has to be done using BigInteger. Long values(as the other post asks about) does not store big enough values compared to what i need</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go about formatting 1200 to 1.2k in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753251/how-to-go-about-formatting-1200-to-1-2k-in-java)

Comment: I explained why that is false. They use long and for my purpose I HAVE to use BigInteger. Long cannot store big enough values. Edited post to add that detail even clearer.

Comment: Way bigger than `9223372036854775807`? All of your examples fit in a `long`. What would be the expected result for `10000000000000000000`?

Comment: What would be the expected result for 1234567? Should it be 1.234m, 1.234567m or 1234.567k?

Comment: RobertKock: 1.234m. Tunaki: added many examples

Comment: You already fount the other question; can't you extrapolate the solution from long to BigInteger?

Comment: Nope. BigInteger uses more String values in order to fit everything into there without it getting out of bounds(I hate the limit). [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide the value until a value less then 1000 is retrieved.
Determine the suffix (K, M, etc.) by means of the number of times you divided.
Determine the decimals using the remainder of the last division.

For instance:

```
public String formatNumber(BigInteger value)
{
  // Initialize suffixes
  String[] suffixes = new String[]{null, 'k', 'M', ....};

  // Initialize divider
  BigInteger thousand;
  thousand = new BigInteger(1000);

  // Initialize divisions
  BigInteger final_value;
  BigInteger remainder;
  int        nr_divisions;
  final_value = value;
  remainder = null;
  nr_divisions = 0;

  // Divide until final value less then 1000
  BigInteger[] division;
  while (final_value.compareTo(thousand) >= 0)
  {
    division = final_value.divideAndRemainder(thousand);
    final_value = division[0];
    remainder = division[1];
    nr_divisions++;
  }

  // Maybe no divisions
  if (nr_divisions == 0)
    return (value.toString());

  // Determine suffix
  // Some check required since number of divisions may exceed the number of suffixes provided
  String suffix;
  suffix = suffixes[nr_divisions];

  // Compose string
  return (final_value.toString() + "." + String.format("%03d", remainder.intValue()) + suffix);

} // formatNumber
```

Comment: What I meant is that you should take suffix 'K' in case you divided by 1000 the original value only once. Dividing it by 1000 twice, the suffix would be 'M'.

Comment: This algorithm could be a useful answer if some code were to be added.

Comment: I edited the answer, providing a possible algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

From BigInteger to string: [How to convert locale formatted number to BigInteger in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101470/how-to-convert-locale-formatted-number-to-biginteger-in-java)

After that you need something like this (needs improvements):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    print("1.034");
    print("21.034.234");
    print("1.034.234.321");


}

private static String convert(String points) {
    String[] letters = new String[]{"k", "M", "G"};
    int size = points.length();
    String after = points;
    if (size > 3) {
        int firstPoint = points.indexOf(".");
        after = points.substring(0, firstPoint + 4); 
        int x = (size - firstPoint - 3)/4;
        after += letters[x];
    }
    return after;
}

static void print(String x) {
    System.out.println(x + " is " + convert(x));
}
```

It's really not that hard to write piece of code (like less than 20 lines)